# Python Request Not Returning Full HTML Source Code

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to retrieve full HTML source code but I am finding it only returns partial.

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests 
HEADERS ={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
url = 'https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/products/louis-vuitton-and-nike-air-force-1-by-virgil-abloh-white-white-white-nvprod3690049v/1A9V88'

req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
page_soup = soup(req.text, "html5lib")
print(page_soup)
```

If you vist the website and its source code you will find it is 181 lines long. But in the code it returns 45 lines long.

Any idea what im doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I think you are getting stuck at Challenge Validation. The site uses anti-bot protection of some sort. Using Selenium seems feasible than using requests in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `page_soup.getText()` to get the entire text out of the beautifulSoup object